# How to selectively avoid drawing edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing, tikz-graphs

When using tikz `\graph` macro, is it possible to selectively *not* draw one of the edges? For example, in the image below, is it possible to skip drawing the edge between b and a? I tried with `edge from parent` but it didn't help.

[image: minimal graph]

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{vertex/.style={
    anchor=center,
    circle,
    draw
  }
}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [
  binary tree layout,
  nodes={vertex},
] {
  b -- {
    a,
    c
  }
};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change an edge coming into a node with the key [`target key style`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/target:edge:style) which means you can apply the [graph operator `-!-`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/-!-) for an individual target:

```
target key style = -!-
```

For convenience, the first char handler `>` exists that forwards its arguments to `target key style`:

```
> -!-
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{vertex/.style={anchor=center, circle, draw}}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [binary tree layout, nodes=vertex] {
  b -- { a[target edge style = -!-],
         c }
};
\tikz \graph [binary tree layout, nodes=vertex] {
  b -- { a[> -!-],
         c }
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Qrrbrbirlbel. TiKZ keeps impressing me even after using it for a few years :-)